# Can one prevent Antimalware Executable to start hogging CPU for extended periods each time some network adapter gets active?

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, read-write

[Another article told me](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/can-one-prevent-antimalware-executable-to-start/14d43f26-c682-4b3d-80b6-59ae754b8649?auth=1&rtAction=1444003211636) that the memory hogs is caused by Windows Defender scans. I followed the instructions that tell me to uncheck the boxes in Idle, Power, and Network for each of the 4 tasks that Defender has. The process is still in task manager, but I'm assuming it will always be there, at around 39.7 MB of memory. Will it still do write to disks and hog memory again?

Comment: install a different AV suite and Defender gets disabled.

Comment: Disable Defender, you can do this without installing another AV software, as any good av software will do the same. 39.7mb of memory is hogging?

Comment: @Moab The hogs inlcuded memomry and reading and writing to disk. It had like 110.3 MB and 15.4 Mb/s or something. As of write now (haha pun) defender is not scanning my computer at all since I turned the tasks off, and I'm just going to leave defender on right now at 39.7 mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, go into defender settings at the last option and uncheck "use this app"

Comment: Warning: This solution doesn't work on windows 10 since defender settings are changed and the "Use this app" becomes "real time protection". Once you switch it off, windows turns it on later automatically. it's never permanently off.